# query for report of user logins in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Does anyone know how to get a report of user logins in MSSQL that will display the days and number of user logins and logouts in the output?

---

Version 2019

I ran `master.sys.syslogins` but I got this message

> The request for procedure 'syslogins' failed because 'syslogins' is a view object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your question to be divided into two parts:

1. login inventory
2. login events

**Existing logins inventory**

The logins inventory can be achieved with powershell module dbatools. You will install it to your admin's workstation by running

```
install-module dbatools
```

in Powershell.

After you install the Powershell module, you can run

```
get-dbalogin -sqlinstance YourSQLServer\YourInstance | select Name, CreateDate, LastLogin
```

To retrieve list of logins, when they were created and when they logged in the last time. With dbatools Powershell module, you can also periodically running *watch-dbadblogin* command also from dbatools module. You can see help with following commands:

```
 help watch-dbadblogin -examples
 help watch-dbadblogin -detailed
```

or simply

```
 help watch-dbadblogin
```

**Logging in events**
For this part you have to enable Logins auditing. You right-click the SQL server properties, you select "security" in the left pane and for the Login Auditing, set your preferences (a bit more here [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16)). You have to restart SQL server service. By default, only failed logins are audited and are written to SQL error log which you can then read with following sp:

```
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0 , 1, 'Login Failed';
```

The meaning of the parameters is :

- 0 - current log
- 1 - error log
- 'Login failed' - string you're
  searching for.

If above mentioned is not viable path for you, then I recommend enabling native SQL server auditing (left part of the table) in following link:[Netrwix howto](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_audit_sql_server_logins.html)

You can find some good tutorials how to interact with SQL server audit.

Answer (score -4):

Read table `master.sys.syslogins` if your server is old or views `sys.server_principals` and `sys.sql_logins` for the modern version of SQL Server.